# [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin]Multiple Resolved Variables in Github Push Payload for single Generic Variable

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, github-webhook, jenkins-generic-webhook-trigger

I have the generic Variables like one below in my jenkins pipeline

```
        parameters {
            stringParam('DOCKER_FILE', "", "Select the Dockerfile Directory [dirname] to be built")

        }

        genericVariable {
            key("DOCKER_FILE") //maven-mongodb
            value("\$.head_commit.['modified','added'][*]") //all directory names
            regexpFilter("/Dockerfile")
            expressionType("JSONPath")
        }
```

But when I see Github push payload body I can see resolved variables as "DOCKER_FILE":"[]" and "DOCKER_FILE_0":"[]"...This is because I have added 2 (modified,added) in which "DOCKER_FILE" will have all values while _0 and _1 will have their own like

https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/test/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gwt/bdd/github/github-push-get-changed-files.feature

**Scenario:**

**In my Jenkins Pipeline**

For Manual Trigger -> Parameter I have is only **DOCKER_FILE** and "DOCKER_FILE_0" is undefined

For webhook trigger -> Through Generic Variables I will have both DOCKER_FILE and DOCKER_FILE_0

**Query:**

**How can I use the value of **"DOCKER_FILE_0"** in my pipeline for manual trigger?

Or else How can I get "maven-mongodb/file1.txt" from DOCKER_FILE without []
Below are my contributing variables
**

**During Webhook trigger my Contributing variables:**

```
DOCKER_FILE = ["maven-mongodb/file1.txt","maven-mongodb/file2.txt"]
DOCKER_FILE_0 = maven-mongodb/file1.txt
DOCKER_FILE_1 = maven-mongodb/file2.txt
```

ie.DOCKER_FILE_0 will be automatically created during push event with generic webhook trigger

Comment: Is your question, "How can I get a value populated by a Github Push Notif plugin on a push notif also populated when my trigger is not a push notif?"

Comment: When I push ,webhook triggers means I will get DOCKER_FILE & DOCKER_FILE_0..But for Manually trigger the job I have defined only DOCKER_FILE parameter..So the other one will be undefined and cant use it in pipeline

Comment: @MaratC Kindly check the updated description of my question